# Applying a condition in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataset, slice

I have a dataset with over 20000 rows, that goes pretty much like this :

```
dataset.head()
```

[image]

So, what I want is only to keep the Ids that have as a date : 2018, 2017 and 2016 combined (Not just one of them). For example:  I won't have Id 1, but will have Id 3.
How can I do that in Pandas?

I'm sorry if the question sounds silly for you, I'm just a beguinner.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, use `set intersection` to identify those matching years & `boolean indexing` to extract those id's matching the criteria.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
                   "date": [2016, 2017, 2018, 2016, 2017, 2016, 2017, 2018]})

year_ = {2016, 2017, 2018}

filter_ = (
    df.groupby('id')['date'].agg(list).apply(
        lambda x: True if len(set(x).intersection(year_)) == len(year_) else False)
)

print(filter_[filter_.eq(1)].index.values)

[1 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since 20,000 rows is not a "large" dataset, you can get away with a relatively simple method using groupy and set operations:

```py
def has_dates(x, dates={2016, 2017, 2018}):
    return dates.issubset(set(x))

grouped = dataset.groupby('ID_NUMBER')
mask = grouped.DATE.unique().apply(has_dates)

print(mask[mask].index.values)
```

Here we are grouping the data by the `ID_NUMBER` to get grouped frames for each ID, then checking whether the desired `dates` you are looking for is a subset of the unique dates associated with that particular index.

The `mask` is a boolean series which is `True` for IDs matching your condition, so you can grab it's index values to view all of the IDs which you are interested in, or alternatively use `dataset.loc[mask[mask].index]` to extract the rows from your dataset.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me whether you are also interested in the third column? If all you need is the list of all ID_NUMBER that appear for all three dates, the simplest solution I think is

```
def get_num_id(date):
    r_dataset = dataset[dataset['DATE'] == date]
    return set(r_dataset['NUMBER_ID'])

s = get_num_id(2016) & get_num_id(2017) & get_num_id(2018) # is a set
l = list(s) # if you prefer a list
```